# I feel scared I pass that hospital every day when I go to work

Tags: grammar

I read a piece of news that there is one old man in my city is having Coronavirus. He is now in the hospital. I want to say" I feel scared because I pass that hospital every day when I go to work." 
Is the sentence correct?

Comment: It's correct.  There are many other ways the idea might be expressed, but nothing wrong with that one (if you include "because", as you do in the body of your question).

Comment: How about this one " I pass that hospital on the way to work each day so I feel scared."